# Font Awesome Unicode (NUXT)

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I'm not even sure if this is possible but cannot find any examples or documentation.
Is there any way to use the Unicode for font awesome with NUXT? We've imported font awesome with no problems into the NUXT config and are successfully using the icons directly in the template `<fa :icon="['fas', 'search']"></fa>`  <-- that works.
what we're trying to achieve is using the unicode in css with the ::after.

anyone have any ideas? any help or direction is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show your CSS code?

Comment: sorry totally forgot that.  `  .navbar .dropdown-toggle::after {
    position: absolute;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    margin-left: 0.3em;
    content: '\f107';
    vertical-align: top;
    border: none;
    font-family: "Font Awesome\ 5 Free";
    font-weight: 900;
  }`